# Can't find annotations like @Entity

Tags: hibernate

I have a large Java app that uses Hibernate 5.1.17. I wish to upgrade to 6.2.6. I removed the old jars and installed the new one.

I'm using Java 17.

The first thing I am seeing is that it can't resolve my annotations such as @Entity, @Table, @Column, @Id, @ManyToOne, etc.

I've been looking all over the net. Plenty of examples on how to use those annotations but no examples of where I can find them (what import, what jar).

Sure appreciate some help.

Comment: I found things like \@Entity
in jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar using
import jakarta.persistence.*
But I stall can't find \@Where